# How to remove the Double Quotes and change data type to String in Google Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

These values are in JSON object type, I want to change them String and remove the Double qoute sign. I have tried replace and trim function but they need string as input.

[image]

I have tried replace and trim functions and cast function also but they require input to be in string format.

```sql
Select replace(cast([column name] as string), "\"") from [table name]
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `JSON` column to `STRING` you can use the [`JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_scalar) function. Example:

```sql
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT JSON '[{"day_of_week": "SUNDAY", "from": "06:00:00", "to": "15:00:00"}]' as json_data
)
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(j.day_of_week) as day_of_week,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(j.from) as `from`,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(j.to) as `to`
FROM sample, UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(sample.json_data)) j
```

Output:
[image]